# Revert [openoffice.org]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

We have [openoffice](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/openoffice) which is synonomized with [openoffice.org](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/openoffice.org) as the primary.  The OpenOffice suite is still around, but not OpenOffice.org.  Around five years ago, it became Apache OpenOffice.  I updated the wiki for [openoffice.org](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/openoffice.org), but the tag title is no longer correct.  The simplest solution is to move the wiki and excerpt to [openoffice](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/openoffice) and reverse the direction of the synonym.

Comment: Just to clarify, [https://www.openoffice.org/](https://www.openoffice.org/) is still the official place to get OpenOffice (now Apache OpenOffice).

Comment: @RockPaperLizard, that .org is part of the URL.  If it was still openoffice.org, the web site would be openoffice.org.org.  :-)

Comment: Lol... correct!  I just didn't people to misinterpret what you wrote and think the [openoffice.org](https://www.openoffice.org/) website is no longer the best place to get OpenOffice!  It still is, even now that it is an Apache project.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard You might be interested in this recent Linux Weekly News article: https://lwn.net/SubscriberLink/699755/533f89639e8b53f0/

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan, interesting reading.  I hadn't followed all that behind-the-scenes action.  All of the discussion about people expecting apologies--what, did they pee in each other's coffee or something?

Comment: It seems like a real mess, alright. From what I can gather, Oracle are mostly responsible for driving the developer community out of OpenOffice (causing them to start LibreOffice) when they realised that they couldn’t make money from the project (after buying Sun). Apparently, IBM threw some more oil on the fire. It’s a pity because OpenOffice is a good name with decent brand recognition. More recent discussion: https://lwn.net/Articles/699047/  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12411747 https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12456071

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Thanks for the article. I watched some of the AOO / LO mess from the sidelines. The level of maturity was like watching egocentric small children bickering. Recently, I considered contributing to LibreOffice. But before I did, I performed some research to see if they had evolved into respectful adults. Unfortunately, the maturity of several of their key players (including a board member) had further regressed. Kindness & respect were absent. No one in the project was willing to stand up to them. I elected to not contribute and can no longer recommend LibreOffice.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I suppose that's people for you. You get similar unsavoury behaviour in many organisational splits; it's particularly bad for political and religious organisations whose members were previously united through an over-arching ideology that trumped any lesser disagreements. In this case, MS Office is the clear winner which is dis-spiriting. Personally, I've moved to using Vim, Markdown and Pandoc for documents and Gnumeric for spreadsheets but it'd be nice to be able to make a clear FOSS recommendation for less-technical friends and family who are using MS Office.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Great analysis.  I agree, it would be nice to have a clear FOSS recommendation for an office suite.  One thing I've learned is that most people really only use 1 or 2 applications from within a suite, so recommending standalone FOSS applications that are not part of a suite is very much appreciated by those with less technical experience.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard, I was really impressed with the Calligra office suite's UI (that project is part of KDE).  It just seems like a well-thought-out, intuitive design.  The software's operation isn't quite ready for prime time in some places, though.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan "less technical" in your comment should be stricken. It implies that all tech savvy people should be using FOSS alternatives to MS Office. There's a subset of tech savvy which prefers MSO. I am one of those. I'll switch when FOSS alternatives offer features or workflow I desire that are not available otherwise. Mostly this is due to my work environment which is Windows. Linux, at least, is making inroads there, even if FOSS is not. The rest is because MS maintains UI and feature superiority in Office.  However I realize this is a preference.  Others' preferences differ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is done, the synonym mapping has been swapped